# SQL: how to include records that dont exist

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I am making a query where I sort posts by upvotes. I have table `posts` and `votes(post_id, user_id, vote)`, where vote can be 1 or -1. So now my problem is if post does not have any upvotes it won't show in result at all.
My query:

```
SELECT P.* FROM `vicoteka-api`.posts P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) vote_count FROM `vicoteka-api`.votes 
    WHERE vote = 1 GROUP BY post_id
) V ON P.id = V.post_id
ORDER BY V.vote_count DESC
```

How can I include posts that don't exist in `votes` pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `left join` with `coalesce` to get posts with no votes.

```
SELECT P.*,COALESCE(v.vote_count,0) as vote_count 
FROM `vicoteka-api`.posts P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) vote_count 
           FROM `vicoteka-api`.votes 
           WHERE vote = 1
           GROUP BY post_id
           ) V ON P.id = V.post_id
ORDER BY vote_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamsi's answer is correct.  If performance is a consideration, you might want to compare it to:

```
SELECT P.*, COUNT(v.post_id) as vote_count 
FROM vicoteka-api.posts P LEFT JOIN
     vicoteka-api.votes v
     ON P.id = V.post_id AND v.vote = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY vote_count DESC;
```

Or, what might even be better:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM vicoteka-api.votes v
        WHERE P.id = V.post_id AND v.vote = 1
       ) as vote_count 
FROM vicoteka-api.posts p 
ORDER BY vote_count DESC;
```

The latter two allow an index to be used for the `JOIN`.  The last one even saves effort on the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.*, V.POST_ID, V_COUNT, VOTE_COUNT FROM `vicoteka-api`.posts P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT post_id, COUNT( NVL(vote_count),0) AS V_COUNT, VOTE_COUNT
FROM `vicoteka-api`.votes 
GROUP BY post_id, vote_count
) V ON P.id = V.post_id and V.vote_count <> -1
ORDER BY V.vote_count DESC
```

Correct me if I am wrong.